# Lost focus by Enter Key detection (Python-Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

I want to enhance usability of my Python-Kivy program. In the following program example, I want to allow users to operate it even if they don't have mouse. (by keyboard input.)
(1) In the first dialog (MyLayout2), user input in Textbox easily as the textbox has focus
(2) Hit Enter keyboard key to go to next dialog (MyLayout1)
(3) Hit Enter keyboard key to go to (1) (MyLayout2 again)
However in the 2nd (1), after (3), the focus of Textbox is lost. Any idea how to cope with this problem?

## Main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.core.window import Window

sm = ScreenManager()
class MyLayout1(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyLayout2(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyScreen(Screen):
    dialog_number = 0
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.gridlayout = None
        self.gridlayout = MyLayout2()
        self.add_widget(self.gridlayout)
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._keydown)

    def _keydown(self,*args):   
        if (args[2] == 40):
            if self.dialog_number == 0:
                self.button2_clicked()
            elif self.dialog_number == 1:
                self.button1_clicked()

    def _create_layout(self):
        if self.gridlayout is not None:
            self.remove_widget(self.gridlayout)
        self.add_widget(self.gridlayout)

    def button1_clicked(self, *args):
        if self.gridlayout is not None:
            self.remove_widget(self.gridlayout)
        self.gridlayout = MyLayout2()
        self.add_widget(self.gridlayout)
        self.dialog_number = 0

    def button2_clicked(self, *args):
        if self.gridlayout is not None:
            self.remove_widget(self.gridlayout)
        self.gridlayout = MyLayout1()
        self.add_widget(self.gridlayout)
        self.dialog_number = 1

    def find_instance(self, layout):
        c = None
        for c in list(self.children):
            if isinstance(c, layout): 
                break
        return c

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):  
        self.anschoi = MyScreen(name = 'anschoi') 
        sm.add_widget(self.anschoi)
        sm.current = 'anschoi'
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    myApp().run()
```

## my.kv

```
<MyScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 10,40,10,40 
        spacing: 40 

<MyLayout1>:
    Button1:
        id: btn1
        text: 'OK or ENTER key'
        on_release: root.parent.button1_clicked()  


<MyLayout2>:
    txtinput: txtinput
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: txtinput
        text: ''
        multiline: False
        focus: True
    button2:
        id:Button2
        text: 'OK or ENTER key'
        on_release: root.parent.button2_clicked()  

<Button0@Button>:
<Button1@Button>:
<button2@Button>:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly the same problem as your previous question. Just change:

```
Window.bind(on_key_down=self._keydown)
```

to:

```
Window.bind(on_key_up=self._keydown)
```

Again, to avoid the `on_key_up` event (that almost always follows a `on_key_down` event) stealing the focus from your `TextInput`.

Comment: Wonderful, it worked fine! Thank you very much!! You helped me twice!!